# Django - dreaded 'iteration over non-sequence'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Hi I'm looking to populate a list of members, based on where their club comes from.

This is my code:

```
 members = []
 if userprofile.countries.count() > 0:
     for c in userprofile.countries.all():
         clubs = Club.objects.filter(location__country = c)
         for club in clubs:
             members_list = Member.objects.get_members(club)
             for m in members_list:
                 members.append(m)
```

However, when evaluating `for m in members_list:` it throws an 'iteration over non-sequence'

I'm not entirely sure why? Can anyone give me any ideas?!

EDIT:

Solved using the following:

```
members = []
if userprofile.countries.count() > 0:
            members_list = member.objects.filter(memberstoentities__club__location__country__in = userprofile.countries.all())
            for m in members_list:
                members.append(m)
```

Comment: Can you post the source for `Member` model?

Comment: What is `Member.objects.get_members` supposed to return? I'd guess it returns a list, but obviously, it doesn't (`None`?)...

Comment: What does `Member.objects.get_members(club)` do which couldn't be served by `club.member_set.all()`?

Comment: Member.objects.get_members(club) returns a queryset of users associated with that club.

club.member_set.all() does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment unless looking at Member model. But

1. Can't we use .filter with back navigation, instead of get_members
2. Do we need those many loops, and db access inside loop? ex:

clubs = Club.objects.filter(location__country__in = list_of_user_countries)

If your final list is list of members, you can do that as I mentioned above (at least in optimized way)

Comment: Thanks! By compounding the queries and using your method, I've managed to solve it!